# PHP SQLite - prepared statement misbehaves?

Tags: php, sqlite, prepared-statement

I have the following SQLite table

```
CREATE TABLE keywords
(
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 lang INTEGER NOT NULL,
 kwd TEXT NOT NULL,
 count INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 locs TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}'
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX  kwd ON keywords(lang,kwd);
```

Working in PHP I typically need to insert keywords in this table, or update the row count if the keyword already exists.  Take an example

```
$langs = array(0,1,2,3,4,5);
$kwds = array('noel,canard,foie gras','','','','','');
```

I now these data run through the following code

```
 $len = count($langs);
 $klen = count($kwds);
 $klen = ($klen < $len)?$klen:$len;

 $sqlite = new SQLite3('/path/to/keywords.sqlite');
 $iStmt = $sqlite->prepare("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO keywords (lang,kwd) 
 VALUES(:lang,:kwd)");
 $sStmt = $sqlite->prepare("SELECT rowid FROM keywords WHERE lang = :lang 
 AND kwd = :kwd");

 if (!$iStmt || !$sStmt) return;

 for($i=0;$i < $klen;$i++)
 {
  $keywords = $kwds[$i];
  if (0 === strlen($keywords)) continue;
  $lang = intval($langs[$i]);


  $keywords = explode(',',$keywords);
  for($j=0;$j < count($keywords);$j++)
  {
   $keyword = $keywords[$j];
   if (0 === strlen($keyword)) continue;

   $iStmt->bindValue(':kwd',$keyword,SQLITE3_TEXT);
   $iStmt->bindValue(':lang',$lang,SQLITE3_INTEGER);
   $sStmt->bindValue(':lang',$lang,SQLITE3_INTEGER);
   $sStmt->bindValue(':kwd',$keyword,SQLITE3_TEXT);

   trigger_error($keyword);
   $iStmt->execute();
   $sqlite->exec("UPDATE keywords SET count = count + 1 WHERE lang = 
   '{$lang}' AND kwd = '{$keyword}';");

   $rslt = $sStmt->execute();
   trigger_error($sqlite->lastErrorMsg());
   trigger_error(json_encode($rslt->fetchArray()));
  }
 }
```

which generates the following `trigger_error` output

> **Keyword**: noel
> **Last error**: not an error
> **SELECT Result**: {"0":1,"id":1}
>
> **Keyword**: canard
> **Last Error**: not an error
> **SELECT**  Reult:false
>
> **Keyword**:foiegras
> **Last Error**: not an error
> **SELECT Result**: false

From the SQLite command line I see that the three row entries are present and correct in the table with the id/rowid columns set to 1, 2 and 3 respectively.  `lastErrorMsg` does not report an error and yet two of the three `$rslt->fetchArray()` statements are returning `false` as opposed to an array with `rowid/id` attributes.  So what am I doing wrong here?

---

I investigated this a bit more and found the underlying case.  In my original code the result from the first `SQLite3::execute` - `$iStmt-execute()` - was not being assigned to anything.  I did not see any particular reason for fetching and interpreting that result.  When I changed that line of code to read `$rslt = $iStmt->execute()` I got the expected result - the `rowid/id` of the three rows that get inserted was correctly reported.

It is as though internally the PHP SQLite3 extension buffers the result from `SQLiteStatement::execute` function calls.  When I was skipping the assignment my next effort at running such a statement, `$sStmt->execute()` was in effect fetching the previous result.  This is my interpretation without knowing the inner workings of the PHP SQLite3 extension.  Perhaps someone who understands the extension better would like to comment.

Comment: “what am I doing wrong here” What is the goal? What does not work as expected? The data is saved as you say and there are no errors. What is your question at all?

Comment: @feeela looks like DroidOS doesn't expect the select statements to return false. I'm on my phone, but I think the queries aren't getting reinitialized in the for loop.

Comment: I have edited the question to better indicate what I feel does not work quite the way it should.  Basically, I need to get the rowid of the newly created row/updated row. As @Zev says I cannot see why that `select` statement is returning `false` instead of returning a `SQLite3Result` and why - given that it is returning false - there is no `lastErrorMessage`.

Comment: Not the first time I find myself moved to write something along these lines - would the person who voted to "close" my question care to comment on the reasons they chose to vote?  If there was something that required clarification it could have been asked for.  If I have somehow broken the rules of this forum, have not shown adequae research... that could be indicated too.  It is soooo easy to just hit that Close link!

Comment: @DroidOS I need resetup PHP to use it locally, but did you try moving these two lines into the for loop:  `$iStmt = $sqlite->prepare("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO keywords (lang,kwd) 
 VALUES(:lang,:kwd)");
 $sStmt = $sqlite->prepare("SELECT rowid FROM keywords WHERE lang = :lang 
 AND kwd = :kwd");`

Comment: @Zev That would almost certainly help but I did not do that since it would diminish all benefits - other than some SQL injection protection - from using a prepared statement.

Comment: @DroidOS You're right, I just read the docs again on prepared statements. Once the variable is bound though, why are trying to bind it again in the for loop. Shouldn't you just have to update the value of the variables?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169224/discussion-between-droidos-and-zev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `$rslt = NONE;` right after `trigger_error(json_encode($rslt->fetchArray()));` and the correct results appear.

FetchArray can only be called once and somehow php is not detecting that the variable has changed. I also played with changing `bindValue` to `bindParam` and moving that before the loop but that is unrelated to the main issue.

<strike>It is my opinion that my solution should not work unless there is a bug in php. I am too new at the language to feel confident in that opinion and would like help verifying it.</strike> Okay, not a bug, but a violation of the least surprise principle. The object still exists in memory so without finalizing it or resetting the variable, fetch array isn't triggering.

Comment: I am now doing `$rslt->finalize()` which, according to the docs, closes the result set.  The docs are not too clear on what exactly might happen if a result set is not finalized.  This requires input from someone who knows how the PHP SQLite3 extension works.